# How to get the data of an ethereum block using web3

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js

This is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract Signup {
   string fStudentId;
   string fLocation;
   
   function setInfo(string _fStudentId, string _fLocation) public  {
       fStudentId = _fStudentId;
       fLocation = _fLocation;
   }
   function getInfo() public constant returns (string, string)    {
       return (fStudentId, fLocation);
   }
}
```

I put studentId & location in to block, and how do I get this info by using web3?

I try to use:

`web3.eth.getBlock(7).then(console.log);`

but get:
[image]

Where is my studentId & location?

Comment: To get the values you should use the contract's methods using web3. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.8/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean when you say "I put studentId & location in to block" but I will try to answer.

You are probably setting state by doing something like

`contract.functions.setInfo(1, "here")`

To retrieve that data you will do

`contract.functions.getInfo()`

---

The actual state of the ethereum blockchain is composed into a merkle trie and referenced by `stateRoot`. So as you can see, there is not an easy way to find this data based on the block header you have.

To retrieve the data from your contract you have a few options:

1. Use your getInfo method as I described above
2. Look up the transaction where you execute `setInfo` and parse the inputs from the transaction receipt
3. Emit an event from your contract whenever `setInfo` is called and set up a listener for a filter that will be called any time a transaction that emits your contract's event occurs
4. Run a node and get the raw data from the block instead of just the block header